# Using Ubuntu Squid as a relay with auto-configuration

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

I am behind a farm of corporate proxies, which block access to SkyDrive, among other sites, but the firewall still allows to pass through. Is it possible to use Ubuntu's Squid as a relay proxy, which would authenticate me with the corporate proxies using active directory uid/pwd for most sites, but at the same time, would make the request to be direct for selected few? Would also be nice if it was possible to tell Squid to use the auto-configuration file (pac file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing something much more "simpler". Downloaded the PAC file to local disk than used 
file:///{drive}:/{folder}/{pacfile} as an automatic configuration script location. Proceeded with adding blocked domain to direct access hosts.